# Trading places SF novel

Tags: story-identification, novel

Over on [rec.arts.sf.written](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.arts.sf.written/vf0mmsQk_l8), this YASID has been asked twice, with no answer. Anyone?

> Do you know this book? It's a paperback book I had in the mid-60s...about
>   two (eventually) physically similar guys, from two completely different
>   environments, who trade places for a month or two.
>
> The one from our (1950s) world is a meek, sickly British prole, living his
>   life of quiet desperation in a terrace house with his wife. The other is a
>   bored starship captain, weary with ennui at how he can have anything he
>   desires, and all has become so predictable. They both decide to commit
>   suicide by jumping into the river -- but instead of the quick impact they
>   both wind up flying through a featureless gray void, passing each other
>   midway -- and then each is somehow mistaken for the other, futuristic
>   medicine rapidly rendering our hero into a strong, vigorous guy who gets
>   into his new  role, using unexpected tactics to win space battles.
>   Meanwhile back in England our other hero beats up the neighborhood bully,
>   winning 'his' wife's and the neighbors' adoring respect . Then somehow,
>   again they're hurtling through the void, passing (and this time
>   recognizing) each other, and upon arrival finding that each has improved
>   the other's lot, happy endings all around.
>
> "Tomorrow" may have been a word in the title. Any idea what it was?